# Azure DNS is public records

Tags: domain-name-system, azure-dns

I have created DNS zones for a few domains.

From my PC is I go to nslookup
And then do 
server ns1-06.azure-dns.com
It connects to that server and will use for name resolution.
Then when I tell it to look up a record, it errors and says it can't find a record.

However if I do c:> nslookup

> server 40.90.4.6  (that's the IP for ns1-06.azure-dns.com)
>   Then request a record....it pulls up the record and shows the proper entry for the record.

So why is Azure DNS working only when the IP address is queried vs it's FQDN?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work for me with either the FQDN or the ip address. The answer I get is "Query Refused", which tells me that the server doesn't perform recursion... which makes sense, the server is more than likely only hosting the DNS zones and not acting as a recursive DNS server for DNS clients.

Comment: But I thought the point of Azure DNS was to be able to host your domains in their DNS fabric???  Did I miss something?
I did open port 53 for the inbound firewall rule in the NSG
So maybe give that a try and then point to the IP address to see if it works for you.

Comment: Yes, they resolve DNS for the DNS zones that they host, not for everyone else's DNS. They're not a public recursive resolver like Google's public recursive resolvers (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4).

Comment: It's not a firewall issue. I can reach them just fine. The answer to my query was "Query Refused", which tells me they don't perform recursive resolution for domains not hosted with them. If you tell us the domain name of the the domain you have hosted with them we can test that.

Comment: I am not looking for recursion.
I am only querying for records that I know exist in the domains I added 

e.g.
I create a domain called 
acme.com
Then I add a record
exchange.acme.com

If I do nslookup and connect to the IP address, it will return the information for the 'exchange.acme.com' record
If I do nslookup and connect to the FQDN of the server, then it errors and doesn't return anything.

Comment: If you give us the actual/real domain name we can help test and troubleshoot. Without it we have no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: Ok. 
Domain is:: d2ms.com
A record you can query for is 'exch.d2ms.com'
In the Azure Portal, it lists this: ns1-06.azure-dns.com as the name server
It's IP is: 40.90.4.6

Comment: Also I am running nslookup from my cmd prompt to test this

Comment: That domain seems to have it's name servers elsewhere, not in Azure.

Comment: https://tools.dnsstuff.com/#dnsReport|type=domain&&value=d2ms.com

Comment: https://intodns.com/d2ms.com

Comment: Correct.  My on premise DNS servers are currently the ones I am using for handling the domain records
I am putting them in Azure and testing for now.  We have not pointed the lookups to use Azure DNS yet.
But I can still connect to the Azure DNS servers and get back records that it is holding when I use nslookup and tell it to use a specific DNS server

Answer (score 0):

Using various tools
The Azure DNS works correctly
For whatever reason, running nslookup and then specifying a name server, it didn't work properly
But if you ran nslookup supplied a record and supplied the DNS server all in one line it would work properly.

I went ahead and moved over two zones to Azure and pointed to the Azure DNS
It worked as it should.